# Strip spaces from Django form

Tags: python, django

I am getting the form with through a post request:

```
form = ReportDataForm2(req.POST)
```

I am trying to strip spaces from all fields by:

```
for element in form:
      form[element] = form[element].strip()
```

But this does not seem to do anything.

I also tried stripping at the point where I am receiving the data:

```
            id = form.cleaned_data['id'].strip()
```

Not working either.

I am new to Django so don't know how forms are treated.

Comment: Why do you need to strip the data? `form.cleaned_data['start_date']` is probably a `datetime` object and won't have a strip method?

Comment: I am stripping on a different field. Not the date fields. I added the strip method to the text field but didn't work

Comment: Can you provide the data that the call to strip is not working on?

Comment: In Django 1.9 you get this for free with the strip kwarg in the CharField constructor [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.CharField.strip)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about this:
You extend the CharField class, create your own Field, and use that anytime you want to have stripped field?

```
class StrippedCharField(CharField):
     """Newforms CharField that strips trailing and leading spaces."""
     def clean(self, value):
         if value is not None:
             value = value.strip()
         return super(StrippedCharField, self).clean(value)
```

There's been a long discussion on whether form data stripping should be handled by Django or not. The [discussion was resurrected](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/django-developers/D1GBj9VB9sk/gDm5PFHMKSUJ) recently but the actual thread [started about 7 years ago](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/6362)

I haven't tested the code above myself. [The solution was pulled from this forum discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/django-users/rQFQHB_Z0hM)

Answer (score 1):

A good place to validate your form fields is the `clean_<fieldname>()` method. `<fieldname>` is the name of the field you want to validate. For example, if you want to validate a field called `name`, you will define a `clean_name()` method to validate it.

An elaborate example:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    text = forms.CharField(...)
    ...

    def clean_text(self):
        stripped_text = self.cleaned_data['text'].strip()
        # do some other validation if you want...
        return stripped_text
```

Apart from stripping, you can do all sorts of validation there.

[See docs for more on validation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/forms/validation/).